# How do I mimic props available = TRUE in my unit test so I can test my react component in isolation

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I am trying to unit test a component that generates a list of child components and in my code to avoid running array.map on an empty object, I have a conditional that checks to make sure the props are available.  When I render the component in the browser it works, but when I try to run the unit test, even using `async/await`, it always goes to the `props = false` branch.

I have the props hardcoded into the test and it still does not work.  How do I mimic `props=true` so that I can test the component rendering the list?

I have tried to use `async/await`, so there is a pause to allow the props to become available.  Somehow I think something else is going on here, but I can't figure it out.

This is my component:

```
const OratorList = ({ orators }) => {
    return (
        <div className="orator-list section">
            {orators ? orators.map(orator => {
                return (
                    <Link className="orator-item" to={ROUTES.ORATOR+'/'+orator.id} key={orator.id} >
                        <OratorSummary orator={orator} key={orator.id} />
                    </Link>
                )

            }): null}

        </div>
    );
};

export default OratorList;
```

This is the test:

```
describe('Orator List', () => {
    test('it renders a list of orator cards with their first name, last name, age, and parent of the orator', () => {

        //Arrange
        const orator1 = {
            orator: {
                id: 1,
                firstName: 'Jonathan',
                lastName: 'Smith',
                dateOfBirth: '2005-09-24',
                parentName: 'Denise Smith'
            }
        }
        const orator2 = {
            orator: {
                id: 2,
                firstName: 'Amy',
                lastName: 'Smith',
                dateOfBirth: '2007-01-15',
                parentName: 'Denise Smith'
            }
        }
        const orator3 = {
            orator: {
                id: 3,
                firstName: 'Susan',
                lastName: 'Smith',
                dateOfBirth: '2011-06-06',
                parentName: 'Denise Smith'
            }
        }

        const props = [orator1, orator2, orator3]

        //Act
        const {getByText} = render(<OratorList {...props} />)


        //Assert

        const nameNode = getByText(`${orator1.orator.firstName} ${orator1.orator.lastName}`)
        const parentNode = getByText(`${orator1.orator.parentName}'s Family`)

        expect(nameNode).toBeDefined()
        expect(parentNode).toBeDefined()


    })
})
```

And this is what prints out when the test fails:

> Unable to find an element with the text: Jonathan Smith. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div
      class="orator-list section"
    />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass in props as:

```
<OratorList {...props} />
```

an array is just being spread into props, instead what you have to do is:

```
const props = [orator1, orator2, orator3];
const {getByText} = render(<OratorList orators={props} />)
```

with `orators` being name of the prop recieved in `OratorList`